# Error in filtering after join in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

My used code looks like this: (just a simple join)

```
tbl(sc, 'dez') %>% inner_join(tbl(sc, 'deg'), by = c("timefrom" = "timefromdeg", "elemuid")) %>% 
    filter(number.x > 2500) %>% glimpse()
```

The content of the single dataframe doesn't matter. The join itself would work. To save computing power I would like to filter (or whatever) directly after joining.

But now I get the error message that *Spark* can't ressolve variable *number.x* .

I don't get it, because the variables are part of the error message:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`number.x`' given input columns: [elemname.x, kind.y, timefrom, timetodeg, timeto, kind.x, elemuid, elemname.y, number.y, number.x]; line 7 pos 7;
'Project [*]
+- 'Filter ('number.x > 2500.0)
   +- SubqueryAlias yoxgbdyqlw
      +- Project [elemuid#7505 AS elemuid#7495, elemname#7506 AS elemname.x#7496, kind#7507 AS kind.x#7497, number#7508 AS number.x#7498, timefrom#7509 AS timefrom#7499, timeto#7510 AS timeto#7500, elemname#7512 AS elemname.y#7501, kind#7513 AS kind.y#7502, number#7514 AS number.y#7503, timetodeg#7516 AS timetodeg#7504]
         +- Join Inner, ((timefrom#7509 = timefromdeg#7515) && (elemuid#7505 = elemuid#7511))
            :- SubqueryAlias TBL_LEFT
            :  +- SubqueryAlias dez
            :     +- HiveTableRelation `default`.`dez`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [elemuid#7505, elemname#7506, kind#7507, number#7508, timefrom#7509, timeto#7510]
            +- SubqueryAlias TBL_RIGHT
               +- SubqueryAlias deg
                  +- HiveTableRelation `default`.`deg`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [elemuid#7511, elemname#7512, kind#7513, number#7514, timefromdeg#7515, timetodeg#7516]
```

A `collect()` after joining is not an options, because then I am running out of memory. Is there any posiblity to make stuff happen.

I would be very happy about help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Don't use default `suffix` (`c(".x", ".y")`):

```
set.seed(1)

df1 <- copy_to(sc, tibble(id = 1:3, value = rnorm(3)))
df2 <- copy_to(sc, tibble(id = 1:3, value = rnorm(3)))

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = c("id"), suffix=c("_x", "_y")) %>% 
  filter(value_y > -0.836)

# # Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# # Database: spark_connection
#      id value_x value_y
#   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1    1.  -0.626   1.60 
# 2    2.   0.184   0.330
# 3    3.  -0.836  -0.820
```

**The problem**:

Spark allows deeply nested structure and complex types. `struct` are accessed using dot syntax (remember [window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50010144/6910411) access?), with full path over the fields. That's why, names like `number.x` are ambiguous.

Normally we escape queries with backticks

```
`number.x`
```

but as far as I am aware it is not possible to express this with `dplyr` API (maybe some `rlang` tricks would do, but I cannot think of any right now).

The problem is not really specific to joins. You should avoid having `.` in the names whatsoever. If for some reason you have, you can always drop to native Spark API and resolve the issue:

```
df3 <- copy_to(sc, tibble(value.x = rnorm(42)))

df3 %>% 
  spark_dataframe() %>% 
  invoke("withColumnRenamed", "`value.x`", "value_x") %>%
  sdf_register()

# # Source:   table<sparklyr_tmp_61acdbbc592> [?? x 1]
# # Database: spark_connection
#    value_x
#      <dbl>
#  1 -0.0162
#  2  0.944 
#  3  0.821 
#  4  0.594 
#  5  0.919 
#  6  0.782 
#  7  0.0746
#  8 -1.99  
#  9  0.620 
# 10 -0.0561
# # ... with more r
```